# How to generate fake data object in javascript based on the object properties dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I have an example json object like shown below :

```
{
  "name": "my name",
  "age": 10,
  "cities": [
    {
      "name": "Hello",
      "country": "india",
      "state": "something",
      "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
      "is_active": true
    }
  ],
  "is_present": true
}
```

what i want to do is to generate an object having the same json structure with same properties with with different values and i want these values to have fake data that is appropriate for the properties.

So for a property called email , the value should always be an email and for a property called image , the value should always be an image url.

I know i can use "faker.js" library for generating fake data but how can i make it dynamic so that it works well for whatever json object i use ? how do i make it such that it will automatically figure out the right type of data to be generated by faker js depending on each of the properties.

#### What i have tried so far :

- directly match keys in the object and generate fake data based on manual condition as to which key should generate which type of data.
- do a prefix or suffix key matching to detect type of fake data

But the above methods cover only the basic cases. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: "how do i make it such that it will automatically figure out the right type of data" that's impossible. Unless _your whole codebase_ always has the same type for the same key, e.g. `state` always being the countrie's state (yeah, that doesn't work) there is no way to determine the "right fake data"

Comment: I just pasted a function that I'm working on *actually trying to clone anything but `__proto__` properties are hard to clone*

Comment: btw when u check it out.. just @me if you wanna know how it works(but im heading off to highschhool rn)

Comment: As I looked for the exact same thing you've looked for and could not find anything, I've created a small nice util that does exactly that :). It finds the closest approximate faker function by the property name and path, and returns an object with fake data. WDYT?  https://github.com/orshachar/fake-object

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but I don't think there is a right answer in this situation, this is more of a logical problem rather than a technical problem. The key ingredient missing in the solution is **context**.

You can always Object.keys(), traverse through the json, check if its a number, email or any other data type and generate data dynamically based on that. The issue is if you encounter a number field, without context, you have no idea if its a phone number, an age or the price of something or the total population count.

The next step you could possibly steer towards is having keywords that you check for against key names and that might give you some indicator as to what the key is but that's an uphill battle.

Perhaps if you could describe the use case that you are trying to cater to, someone might help suggest an alternate path.